# how to do package configuration deployment in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I am using SSDT 2015. But my project requirement is to do package configuration deployment because server is having different sql server version like (2014...) used by source systems. Please help me to do package configuration deployment using package parameters/variables in SSIS.

Thanks!

Comment: mention the sql server versions. Open the solution in current version, right click and choose 'convert to package deployment'

Comment: Thank you. Sql server 2014. I am using package parameters for dynamic connection in sharepoint source and OleDB destination. Because of that when i am using 'convert to package deployment' it is throwing this error. "package.dtsx is using parameters. To make it compatible remove parameters."  I need to make Dynamic connection,create config file and then do package deployment.

Comment: Follow this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4309/integration-services-ssis-convert-from-package-deployment-model-to-project-deployment-model/ .  Basically, remove the paramters..then change the deployment type from project to package. After that create package configurations as stated.

Comment: I tried Deployment by package and configuration file using DTEXEC command but failed with following error message.  "Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed " Version number cannot be greater than current version number. Please help me.!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Steps followed:
dtexec /f "C:\Package.dtsx" /conf "Package.dtsConfig"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSDT, go to Project>Properties>Configuration Properties, and set `TargetServerVersion` to 2014.   Then re-build your project and you should be able to deploy it to your 2014 SQL Server.

Comment: When we say SSDT 2015, it implies SQL Server 2016?

Comment: I am facing this error when I run the Package [Fuzzy Grouping Inner Data Flow : Fuzzy Lookup [169]] Error: The data type of column 'Column26_in' is not supported.

Comment: @user9358487 That's an entirely different issue.  You should open a new question for it.